# Removing decimals stops working after tax or currency calculations

Tags: php, string-formatting, decimal

I want to display the price by removing decimals if they are double 00 or to display as superscript for any other value. This works until there is a currency exchange or taxes added to the number. Superscript still works, but whole numbers are being returned with double 00 as superscript.

$24.00 USD should be $24 USD

$24.99 USD should be $24.<sup>99</sup> USD

This is the code I am using:

```
if(round($value, 0) == $value)  
$string .= number_format(($value)) . ' ';   

else

$string .= preg_replace("/\.(\d*)/", "<sup>.$1</sup>", number_format($value,    
(int)$decimal_place, $decimal_point, $thousand_point)) . ' ';
```

What am I missing to remove double 00 after either a currency or tax calculation?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? eg. `$value`, `$decimal_place` etc. It will help others to help you better ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
if(round($value, 0) == $value)
```

By this:

```
if(abs(round($value, 0) - $value) < 0.005)
```

Because the tax and currency computations introduce some floating point imprecision.

Comment: I have been struck with that too before. The other way to get around floating point imprecision I found was to compare strings sprintf("%0.3d", $value1) == sprintf("%0.3d", $value2)

Comment: Thanks for keeping it simple and for the explanation as to why it was happening, makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$money = money_format('%n', $value);

$exploded = explode('.', $money);

$currency = '$';

if($exploded[1] == '00')
{
    $currency .= substr($money, 0, strlen($money) -3);
}else
{
    $currency .= $exploded[0] . '<sup>' . $exploded[1] . '</sup>';
}

$currency .= ' USD';

echo $currency;
```